# calculate expectation of product of two correlated random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, correlation

Problem is like this:
$x$ , $y$ are random variables and $x$ is correlated with $y$(specifically, the distribution of $y$ is depend on $x$).
$x$ ~ Binomial(m,p), $y$ can be zero or positive integer and there is no additional assumption about distribution of $y$.
What i want to show is E[$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{mn-\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}$] > E[$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{mn}$] where n is number of $x_i$'s.
It seems obvious that it is true but i'm not sure. How can i show that it is always true?
Thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something?  This does not depend on correlation at all.  On per-sample-point basis the left-side fraction $>$ the right side fraction, if $0 \le \sum y_i < mn$.  OTOH if $\sum y_i \ge mn$ is possible  then the left side fraction can become undefined or negative and the desired inequality is false.